# Can rabbits lose fur when stressed?

Tags: health, rabbits, psychology

My rabbit is really used to people, and doesn't like other rabbits, so she is the only one I have. Before I went on vacation I made sure that she was brushed really well. We took her to my friend's house where she was getting all the care that was needed, as well as the communication with people. We figured that if we left her alone, she would just get depressed. However, when we came back she was shedding like crazy, even though she wasn't at all before we left. Can rabbits lose fur when they are stressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rabbits molt.  Usually with seasonal change, but if you took your rabbit out of a climate controlled area (like your home) and into the warm or cool air outside, even for just a short time, that can trigger a molt.  This is a mechanism your rabbit uses to help keep warm or cool depending on the need.  I would not worry too much about that.

As to your question, my answer is almost assuredly yes.  It is County and State Fair time in the midwestern United States.  That means we are showing our rabbits quite a bit.  And this weekend when I picked up a rabbit, that has won Best of Breed several times in the last few months, to put her on the table, her hair literally poofed up.  Her beautiful shiny black coat was gone in an instant, replaced by patchy and dieing fur.  It is not uncommon for this to happen, rabbits can get stressed easy and even the most show hardy rabbit can have a bad day.  Usually the molt will clear up in a week or two.

One thing you can do to help is provide a supply of black oil sunflower seeds.  A tea spoon a day for week is plenty.  This is a trick that show breeders use to help a molting rabbit get back into condition quicker.

Comment: We have been back from vacation for over a week, and she isn't shedding anymore, and seems relaxed.